# Bitcoin-Qt frozen catching up/sync with Bitcoin in new wallet

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, network

I downloaded [Bitcoin-Qt](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin-Qt), got it running, had 15 weeks or so left to catch up (sync) when I purchased some bitcoins and had them sent to my new wallet.

Then to my horror, Bitcoin-Qt has frozen with four weeks to go. It has been running 48 hours without any change in changed blocks left. I have restarted my computer, rebooted the modem, all the simple things but no love.

What can I do to access this wallet? I'm new to all this. I only ever used my online wallet address before.

Comment: What version of Bitcoin-QT are you running? One of the newer versions significantly increased the synchronization speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the `wallet.dat` file from the bitcoin-qt installation at the time got the wallet address that you sent the money to you can use that with a new bitcoin-qt installation to try to make it work. If you don't have that `wallet.dat` file anymore the money is lost.

As for the problems downloading the blockchain, are you sure you have enough space? It's about 12 GB now. It sometimes take a very long time to download and may just look like it's sitting around for a while doing nothing, then pick up again a while later.

Comment: Yupp backed up wallet, before and after I encrypted it in my panic.... Was scared to uninstall and reinstall as I couldn't find anywhere to open a backed up wallet, as for space, I'd be really surprised to find I don't have 12 gig on my c drive, but will check that too when I get home, thanks heaps for help hey!!!

Comment: P.s. I figured 48 hours was long enough for it sitting around doing nothing before I called it frozen

Comment: @Ric you are probably right about 48 hours, though if you have space and waiting doesn't solve it I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone else have some.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you can export your private keys and import them into a different wallet, like Electrum.

To get your private keys out of bitcoin-qt, click Help, Debug Window, Console tab.

If your wallet is encrypted, you must unlock the wallet with this command:

```
   walletpassphrase "your wallet password" 60
```

To get the private key:

```
   dumpprivkey "addressYouOwn"
```